# Shared hosting error on my Zend based Application

Tags: zend-framework, shared-hosting

I have just sucessfully tested my Zend based application on the localhost.When I deployed it on a shared hosting site I got the error below.It happens whenever I try navigate to protected pages of my application.

```
Warning: include(/home/davidkag/public_html/prototype/application/models/DbTable//Users.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/davidkag/public_html/prototype/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader/Resource.php on line 176
```

I have a feeling that the double slashes

> models/DbTable//Users.php)

are causing this problem.

The error is caused at this particular line in my code:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Model_DbTable_Users' not found in /home/davidkag/public_html/prototype/application/controllers/AuthController.php on line 24
```

How do I trouble shoot this problem.Keep in mind that on my localhost machine its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my problem.It was a case issue.Talk of developing on windows and deploying on linux

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a new test script, with one line, and see what you get:

```
include '/home/davidkag/public_html/prototype/application/models/DbTable//Users.php';
```

Then, remove the double slashes:

```
include '/home/davidkag/public_html/prototype/application/models/DbTable/Users.php';
```

If it's still giving you that warning, then either your path is wrong or your file permissions need to be eased.

P.S. You said 'protected pages' -- are those perhaps not in public_html?

Comment: Derek

The main issue is that on my windows machine it works well.Keep in mind its the Zend Frameworks autoloader which is finding those files.

I just dont understand where the double slashes is coming from on the shared hosting.If I can get rid of it somehow then I proceed to look at the permissions if the error still persists.

Am editing my post to give more details